# Feedburner refuses an Atom feed generated by a Google service

Tags: google-code, feedburner, atom

Here is the Atom feed I want Feedburner to use:

https://code.google.com/feeds/p/ankidroid/downloads/basic

It looks pretty valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <updated>2011-11-07T01:09:09Z</updated>
 <id>http://code.google.com/feeds/p/ankidroid/downloads/basic</id>
 <title>Downloads for project ankidroid on Google Code</title>
...
```

And [feedvalidator.org](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https://code.google.com/feeds/p/ankidroid/downloads/basic) says "*Congratulations! This is a valid Atom 1.0 feed*"

**PROBLEM:**

Feedburner says "*We could not find a valid feed at that address*"

**QUESTION:**

How to make Feedburner accept this feed?
Or is it a known bug?

Comment: Twitterfeed is glad to accept the same feed, and redirect it to a dedicated Twitter account. I then use this dedicated Twitter account's RSS but Feedburner also rejects it, saying "Received HTTP error code 400 while fetching source feed".

Answer (score -1):

You're right it won't work that way, but there's a work around, http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:username

;)